# How Set limit to value - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-4

Hi All I'm trying to set a limit for each progress bar in bootstrap 4.
I want it to trigger on click.

The problem is when ever i click

the value always goes to 100. How can i set a maximum value for each progress bar?

Here's the code.

```
<button>run</button>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-animated limit70"  value="" max="100"></progress>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-animated limit80"  value="" max="100"></progress>

$('button').on('click', function() {
    $('.progress').each(function() {
        var progBar = $(this);
        var perc = progBar.attr("max");
        var userInput = $('input#speed').val(); // in seconds
        var speed = userInput * 10;
        var currentPerc = 0;
        var progress = setInterval(function() {

            if (currentPerc >= perc) {
                clearInterval(progress);

            } else {
                currentPerc += 1;
                progBar.attr('value', (currentPerc) + '');
            }
            progBar.attr((currentPerc) + '');
        }, speed);

    });
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/csmrtrvg/)

Comment: which progressbar plugin you used?

Comment: didn't use a plugin. I used the Bootstrap 4 progress bar just added that jquery to trigger the animation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could work with a custom data attribute:

```js
 $('button').on('click', function() {
   $('.progress').each(function() {
     var progBar = $(this);
     var perc = progBar.attr("max");
     var userInput = $('input#speed').val(); // in seconds
     var speed = userInput * 10;
     var currentPerc = 0;
     var limit = progBar.data("limit");
     var progress = setInterval(function() {

       if (currentPerc >= limit) {
         clearInterval(progress);

       } else {
         currentPerc += 1;
         progBar.attr('value', (currentPerc) + '');
       }
       progBar.attr((currentPerc) + '');
     }, speed);

   });
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="user-controls">
  <button>Click to run</button>
</div>


<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-animated limit70" data-limit="70" value="" max="100"></progress>
<br/>
<progress class="progress progress-striped progress-animated limit80" data-limit="80" value="" max="100"></progress>
```

Updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/csmrtrvg/2/

Comment: That did the trick! :D i was so focus on the value attribute. yeah data-limit ftw!  Thanks buddy.

Newbie salute! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you need a progress bar there [are](https://jqueryui.com/progressbar/), [plenty](https://kimmobrunfeldt.github.io/progressbar.js/), [of](http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/), [libraries](https://github.com/mdix/progress.js) out there that do it for you. There's also a [progress bar for bootstrap](http://www.minddust.com/project/bootstrap-progressbar/).

Comment: Yeah but I'm using bootstrap 4